# Why does adding hibernate-validator-annotation-processor dependency result in "AssertionError: Couldn't find ... java.time.chrono.HijrahDate"?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

So after applying various Java Hibernate Validator dependencies via Maven in IntelliJ, I get the following error whenever I attempt to run the program:

[image]

I have the following dependencies related to Hibernate:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I discovered that by removing the last one (hibernate-validator-annotation-processor), the problem goes away; I can run the program (but I lose any functionality that the annotation-processor package provides). Adding it back reproduces the error perfectly every time. I've never even heard or seen of 'HijrahDate' before and Googling this error yields surprisingly few clues, if any, on how to solve this error. Any ideas on how to fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and I fixed it by using another person's suggestion, that being adding this dependency.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.seratch</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-time-backport</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you please share the source of the solution  or explanation.

Comment: @rajkumar21 I added the above dependency into the pom.xml file of my project, then sync the file using maven, I have a button on Intellij to sync the pom.xm. using maven. And the error disappeared

Comment: @Arkan, Thanks for the info.. Yes I know how to add dependency to a maven project. ;) Here I requested the solution author to share info on how this dependency solves the issue or the source suggestion from where the author got the solution to know more details.